# JAVA Reading from file word by word using BufferedReader

Tags: java, file, oop, io

I have to read from a file Author|Name|Year I need to store this information into class nodes. I must use BufferedReader and FileReader.

```
public class Book {
String author, name;
int years;
}


import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            Book book1 = new Book();
            FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/ZatoIndustries/Desktop/failas.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
            String text = "";
            String line = reader.readLine();
    }
 }
```

Input looks like:
`A|bbbb|2002
 B|cccc|2001
 A|dddd|2000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you read line by line:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
```

split each line by `|`:

```
String[] words = line.split("\\|");
```

you can then assign each of these to a descriptive variable, if you'd like:

```
String year = words[2]
```

This is the easiest way to do this, though you could have a look at [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for something more complicated.

Comment: String.split takes a regex.  You probably meant that to be `line.split("\\|")`.

Comment: I have two questions. 1) Shouldn't we use a while loop for reading the entire content of a file with realLine() method? 2) What about if the file we are trying to read has a first line empty? how we should handle that? tnx in advance

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use Scanner Class with next() Method ,this will be easier .